# Challenging Geometry Problem

Tags: geometry

ABCD is a square. F is a point on BD. CF bisects angle ACD. Q lies on CD. BQ is perpendicular to CF. If AC and BD intersect at E and BQ intersects AC at P, then prove that DQ = 2(PE).

I tried to use Midpoint theorem, but anyhow obstacles come on my way. Can anyone help?

Please do provide an euclidean approach, thank you.

Comment: There are multiple theorems that have been called the [Midpoint Theorem](https://www.google.com/search?q=Midpoint+theorem&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-ContextMenu&ie=&oe=). Which one do you mean?

Comment: The one you linked just now, sir.

Comment: But there are several linked to in that search page. Do you mean the featured one at the top?

Comment: Ya, you are right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm writing this answer referring to Rory's diagram.

First off apply [Menelaus theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27_theorem) in $\triangle CED$ taking $BQ$ as the transversal. This will give you $$\frac{PE}{DQ}=\frac 12 \cdot \frac {PC}{QC}$$

Now since $\triangle CRP \cong \triangle CRQ$ we get $PC=QC$ and the result immediately follows.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a coordinate approach. In this diagram I have taken the side of the square to have length one, and points $A,B,C,D$ have the obvious coordinates.

[image]

Using simple analytic geometry we get these facts:

- $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ has the equation $y=x$.
- $\overleftrightarrow{BD}$ has the equation $y=1-x$.
- $E$ is the point $(\frac 12,\frac 12)$.
- $\measuredangle ACD=45°$.
- $\measuredangle DCF=22.5°$.
- $\overleftrightarrow{CF}$ has the equation $y=(\sqrt 2-1)x$.
- $\overleftrightarrow{BQ}$ has the equation $y=1-(\sqrt 2+1)x$.
- $Q$ is the point $(\sqrt 2-1,0)$.
- $P$ is the point $(1-\frac{\sqrt 2}2,1-\frac{\sqrt 2}2)$
- $DQ=2-\sqrt 2$.
- $PE=1-\frac{\sqrt 2}2$.
- $DQ=2\cdot PE$.

Let me know if you need the details on any of those points. Most are quite simple: the most difficult is finding $PE$.

Comment: Cool, I liked it. I hope you could provide an Euclidean approach too.

Comment: @SwapnilDas: No, this was not a hard question. The hardest part was preparing the diagram and deciding which facts to include and in what order. I don't have the time for a Euclidean approach: I'm off to church then to a movie date with my wife.

Comment: Aahh.. Sure. Enjoy!

Comment: What is this drawn with?

Comment: @Eric: [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/), which I highly recommend and is often advertised on this site. (I'm back now, and I see someone give a Euclidean proof, so I can concentrate on school work.)